# Convert Objects into Hierarchy based on Number Sequence

Tags: c#, linq

I have following data Structure and i want to put covert it in a Hierarchy based on RelationId. This is sorted on RelationId.

Id = 2 has relationId =2 and following two rows has realtionId =0 . That represent the Id=3 and Id=4 are child of Id = 2

```
   Id    Name   RelationId    SortOrder
    1     A       1              1
    2     B       2              2
    3     C       0              3
    4     D       0              4
    5     E       3              5
    6     F       0              6
    7     G       0              7
    8     H       4              8
```

End Result would be like following

```
 Id = 1
  |
 Id = 2  
  |___  Id = 3 , Id = 4

 Id = 5 
  |___ Id= 6 , Id=7

 Id = 8
```

The desired result is as following (for simplicity representing it as List).  This would be a `List<Something>` in C#

```
Result = 
[
   { Id = 1, Name = A, Children = Null },
   { Id = 2, Name = B, Children = [{ Id = 3, Name = C }, {Id = 4, Name = D }] },
   { Id = 5, Name = E, Children = [{ Id = 6, Name = F }, {Id = 7, Name = G }] },
   { Id = 8, Name = H}
]
```

My unsuccessful attempt is as following

```
var finalResult = new List<sampleDataClass>();
var sampleData = GetMeSampleData();   
var count = sampleData.Count();

foreach (var item in sampleData)
{
    var alreadyExist = finalResult.Any(x => x.Id == item.Id);
    var newObject = new sampleDataClass();

    if (!alreadyExist && item.RelationId!= 0)
    {
        newObject = item;
    }

    for (int i = item.SortOrder; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (sampleData[i].RelationId== 0)
        {
            newObject.Children.Add(sampleData[i]);
        }
    }

    finalResult.Add(newObject );
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you make the `RelationId` point at the `Id` of the parent? And just use 0 or -1 or something to mean it's a top level parent?

Comment: It's a sorted array and relationId = 1 is top level

Comment: Added a sortOrder field as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `RelationId` decides whether it is a root or nested element, you could form a group based on these relation and do this. I would suggest using *Linq*

```
List<SomeData> somedata = ... // your data.

int index=0;
var results = somedata
    .Select(x=> new {gid = x.RelationId ==0? index: ++index, item=x})
    .GroupBy(x=> x.gid)
    .Select(x=> {
        var first = x.FirstOrDefault();

        return new 
        {
            Id = first.item.Id,
            Name = first.item.Name,
            Children =  x.Skip(1).Select(s=> new {
                Id = s.item.Id,
                Name = s.item.Name,
            })                      
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Output :**

```
Id=1, Name=A
Id=2, Name=B
    Id=3, Name=C
    Id=4, Name=D
Id=5, Name=E
    Id=6, Name=F
    Id=7, Name=G
Id=8, Name=H
```

Check this [`Working Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PszBXL)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this. Don't know if there can be some more elegant solution

```
  var data = new List<MyDataObject>();
            var SampleData = GetMeSampleData;
            var count = SampleData.Count();
            for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                var rootAdded = false;
                var relationId = SampleData[i].relationId;
                var alreadyExist = data.Any(x => x.Id == SampleData[i].Id);
                var mydataObject = new MyDataObject();
                if (!alreadyExist && SampleData[i].RelationId != 0)
                {
                    mydataObject = SampleData[i];
                    rootAdded = true;
                }


                for(int j=i+1;j<count;j++)
                {
                    if ((SampleData[j].RelationId == 0 && rootAdded))
                    {
                        mydataObject.Children.Add(SampleData[j]);
                    }
                    if (SampleData[j].SubjectId != 0) 
                        break;


                }


                if (rootAdded)
                {
                    data.Add(mydataObject);

                }
```